# How can I add to adapter same items?

Tags: java, android

I'm analyzing instagram followers and following. I want to add adapter, who follow to user and user follow back.

My code:

```
ArrayList<InstagramUserSummary> mutuals = new ArrayList<>(followers);
for (InstagramUserSummary i : followers) {
    for (InstagramUserSummary j : following) {
        if (i.equals(j)) {
            WHAT I HAVE TO DO HERE TO SET ADAPTER mutuals?
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<InstagramUserSummary> mutuals = new ArrayList<>();
for (InstagramUserSummary i : followers) {
    for (InstagramUserSummary j : following) {
        if (i.equals(j)) {
            mutuals.add(i);
        }
    }    
}

// here use mutuals to create Adapter
// change this code and use your custom adapter to show users detail in list
ArrayAdapter<InstagramUserSummary> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mutuals);
```

Comment: Thanks wizard. Its works for me 

Answer (score 1):

To get the intersection between 'followers' and 'following' use

> Collection#retainAll().

```
listA.retainAll(listB);
 // listA now contains only the elements which are also contained in listB.
```

If you want to avoid that changes are being affected in listA, then you need to create a new one.

```
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(listA);
common.retainAll(listB); // common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.
```

Comment: Hi. I can not change this code because InstagramUserSummery do not let me. I'm parsing the followers and following with equals. I have to take which coming from equals.